# Can you make negative values into positive values for easy comparison in a line chart in SPSS?

Tags: spss

Let's say you want to create a line graph which plots a line for the amount of money coming in, and a line for the amount of money going out.

The variable (**moneyIn**) cases for money coming in is positive, like '30,000', but in this case, the amount of money being expended (**moneyOut**) is negative, like '-19,000'.

When I use a line graph to plot these results against eachother across a duration of time, one line is plotted way below in the negative numbers, and the other is plotted with the positive numbers, way above - so they're difficult to compare against one another.

Is there a way to change the negative values into positive ones JUST for the line graph, without computing a new variable or changing the database? I think it would essentially be a sum of (moneyOut*-1), but I don't know if this can be implemented JUST for the chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `TRANS` statement in inline GPL code to flip the sign. Example below.

```
DATA LIST FREE / In Out (2F5.0) Time (F1.0).
BEGIN DATA
1000 -1500 1
2000 -2500 2
3000 -3500 3
4000 -4500 4
END DATA.

GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Time In Out
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Time=col(source(s), name("Time"), unit.category())
  DATA: In=col(source(s), name("In"))
  DATA: Out=col(source(s), name("Out"))
  TRANS: OutPos = eval(Out*-1)
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Time"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Values"))
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Time*In))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Time*OutPos), color(color.blue))
END GPL.
```

[image]